# Should I be using PHP try catch statements? If so am I using them correctly?

Tags: php, try-catch

Ok, so I've looked around stack, google, etc.... There doesn't seem to be a "Correct" answer for this!

Since I started learning `PHP` I've used `try{}catch()` blocks. Some people say that It's wrong and some people say that it's fine. I will continue to use them but before I go ahead Im wondering if Im using them correctly? I am nesting `try { try{}catch() {} }catch(){}` within each other, is this a good practise? Doing this does make the code a bit jumbled! If there was a better way to do what Im doing I'd definitely consider it.

Here is a block of code that I'm working on at the moment, am I wrong in nesting try blocks?

```
try{
        $sql = "select * from users where email = '$email'";
        $stmt = $dbConnection->query($sql);
            $returned = $stmt->fetch();
        if($stmt->rowcount() == 0){
            echo "ERROR";
        }else{

            try{
                $adminId = $returned['uID'];
                $auth_key = generateAuth();
                $sqlHousehold = "INSERT INTO household (adminId, hhName,auth_key) VALUES ($adminId, '$hhName', '$auth_key')";
                $stmt = $dbConnection->query($sqlHousehold);
                $id = $dbConnection->lastInsertId();
                                                    /*Update the newly created householdID into the admins column*/
                $sql = "UPDATE users set hhID = $id where uID = $adminId";
                $stmt = $dbConnection->query($sql);
                                                    /*
                    RETURN the group auth key (Share this to members of fam) + user auth key (store on phone)
                */
                return '{"user_auth_key":"'.$user_auth_token.'", "group_auth_key":"'.$auth_key.'"}';
            }catch(PDOException $e){

            }



        }
    }catch(PDOException $er){
        exit("PDO ExCEPTION !^!^!^!^! " .$er);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is no.

It is just bloating the overhead unnecessarily. I know that it is not always the neatest or most useful option but switch actually runs faster than if else statements: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Also, having debug code in there will slow things down if it gets bigger in the long run. If the code works why waste the resources on debugging it?

**Edit**

Simple error handling logic:

```
// Error handlers
function doError ($e) {
  $_SESSION['error'] = $e;
  header('Location: http://website.com/error.php');
  exit;
}
function getError () {
  if (isset($_SESSION['error']) {
    return $_SESSION['error'];
  } else {
    die('Fatal Error!');
    exit;
  }
}
function clearError () {
  unset($_SESSION['error']);
}

// Error handling when conditions are not met
if (!myCondition()) {
  doError('Condition not met!');
}

// Error template / error.php
$e = getError();    

$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Fatal Error!</title>
  <body>
    <h1>A fatal error occurred</h1>
    <p>'.$e.'</p>
  </body>
</html>
';
echo $html;

clearError();
```

Comment: Interesting! Most people seem to think the same thing. I guess it's not really needed and would be wasting resources (I didn't think of that). Oh really, switch statements are faster? I do agree they aren't very neat...! Although I would rather write if/else statements than have un-neat switch statement code!!

Comment: @James111 I generally only add debug statements while in development or if the need is there to produce an error for a failed result. Usually things just work though so there really is little point in leaving a whole lot of elses/catches in there.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's true. When I'm developing I tend to make sure that everything is as secure as possible which is why I've been using a lot of `if/else` statements.

Comment: @James111 You should dig into the MVC pattern a bit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller - Fatal errors would usually be triggered during initialization and after this point you should not really be worrying about errors unless the possibility is there that some result may fail.

Comment: Ahh. I've heard about the MVC pattern! I'm just not sure if I've got the time to learn how it works and how to implement it properly :|

Comment: In a nutshell, I think it is best in this day and age to standardise the code that you work with. So using platforms that make use of these principals do help. Take a look at Laravel, it's got to be one of the most popular PHP frameworks that implement the MVC pattern.

Comment: I am sourcing myself here as I've spent a long time writing my own framework only to realise that you can never compete with the intelligence of an entire community of passionate developers, its just a better option to join the competition in the end :)

Comment: @James111 "tend to make sure that everything is as secure as possible" adding a layer of debug code actually reduces security of your platform. In production you should have errors and warnings turned off in the PHP configuration. The more info people get about your system the more ways they come up with to use this information to act maliciously... Worst case scenario with errors off? White page and email notification.

Comment: Yeah that's true! Will keep it in mind.

Comment: @James111 Last note... If you're going to display errors then do it gracefully lol. You should have something like a generic error page, then pass the error messages to this so that the user would get the error within your web template and not is some ugly white page with a big orange header or something :)

Comment: @James111 See my update in the answer for some simple error handling logic.

Answer (score 1):

No need to have `inner try catch` block. List all the `exceptions` in the `outer catch block`.

Another `try catch` block inside a `try catch` will increase the overhead & make your code `slower`. Better to use only outer try catch

Comment: Great! I'll remove the nested try catch blocks for sure then.

Answer (score 1):

No need to nest exceptions, you can use multiple `catch` statements for the same `try`, having the same results. E.g.

```
try {
    // some code that might throw exceptions
} catch(ExceptionType1 $ex) {
    // handle the first exception
} catch(ExceptionType2 $ex) {
    // handle the second exception
} catch(ExceptionTypeN $ex) {
    // handle the last exception
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    // catch all other exceptions
}
```

For your particular case, however, you are catching in both `try/catch` the same type of exception (PDOException). Which doesn't need an inner `try/catch` block as it's already handled by the outer `try/catch` block. `PDOException` means most of the time problems when connecting to the database or when querying data, and this is OK to be handled in only one place.

Comment: Ah. Im an idiot for not doing this!

Answer (score 0):

The outer try-catch block will catch all the exceptions caught inside it. If your actions in catch will differ for different parts of the code it appeared in - then nesting them might be useful. Otherwise, if both catch blocks are going to do the same thing - there is no point in doing it.